# How to run ADB commands without Internet, Cable or ethernet

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to run ADB commands on an android tv, but it's subscription is expired due to which it has locked my access to wifi, the ethernet port and the usb port and I was wondering if I can run ADB commands via bluetooth or if there is another way to run ADB commands.